# unable to connect remote server using c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, remote-server

I am using the below code snippet while trying to connect to remote server in visual studio, but it is not working, please suggest.

```
private void bttnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RDP_client.Server = txtServerName.Text;
        RDP_client.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
        IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)RDP_client.GetOcx();
        secured.ClearTextPassword = txtPassword.Text;
        RDP_client.Connect();
        if (RDP_client.Connected.ToString() == "1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("connected");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not connected"); 
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("unable to connect"+ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to remote connect normally to the server?

Comment: yes, i am able to normally connect to the server

Comment: Can you give more details about what's not working?  ex: If an exception is raised, share it with us.